# Проблемы с выводом на печать на реальный принтер

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий код:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
     Image printImg = new Image();
     printImg.Source = bms;
     pd.ShowDialog();
     pd.PrintVisual(printImg , "");
```

Он должен (по идее) выводит на печать изображение, переданное в качестве источника в printImg.

Ситуация следующая: Если вывожу на печать на виртуальный принтер (FinePrint / MS xps writer) всё ок. Изображение отображается, всё корректно.
Вывожу на реальные принтеры (HP, Zebra) изображение не печатается. Совсем, даже пустого листа не выходит. Но если printImg предварительно отобразить на форме то всё ок, всё печатается корректно.

Вопрос: Как выводить на печать printImg без отображения его на форме?

Comment: судя по `PrintVisual` нужно все таки WPF. Ладно, посмотрим и для WPF, давно хотел разобраться с ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение для WPF (XPS)**

```
PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Путь\Имя файла"));       
Nullable<Boolean> print = pDialog.ShowDialog();
if (print == true)
{
  var dv = new DrawingVisual();
  using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen())
  {
    dc.DrawImage(bImage, new Rect(0, 0, bImage.Width, bImage.Heigth));
  }
  pDialog.PrintVisual(dv, "document image");
}
```

Утащено [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df305a6c-4546-4665-a9fb-1b190ea47ec6/how-to-print-bitmapsource?forum=wpf)

**UPD** Также на тему печати в WPF статья Чарльза Петцольда с рабочим примером кода (ссылка на скачивание примера в статье). **[Printing under WPF](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/02/201111.html)**
Отдельное спасибо **VladD** за эту находку.

**UPD**
по уменьшить размеры изображения под область печати можно, например, так:

```
double width, heigth;
if (pDialog.PrintableAreaWidth < bi.Width || pDialog.PrintableAreaHeight < bi.Height)
{
    if (bi.Width - pDialog.PrintableAreaWidth > bi.Height - pDialog.PrintableAreaHeight)
    {
        width = pDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
        heigth = bi.Height * pDialog.PrintableAreaWidth / bi.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        heigth = pDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
        width = bi.Width * pDialog.PrintableAreaHeight / bi.Height;
    }
}
else
{
    width = bi.Width;
    heigth = bi.Height;
}
```

Более подробно в статье по ссылке выше.

**Решение для WinForms + консоль (GDI)**
Вынесено в отдельный **[вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489415/198316)**

Comment: Вот про печать из WPF: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/02/201111.html

Comment: В PrintVisual вы можете вполне передать какой-нибудь `Grid`, у которого установите интересующую вас ширину и высоту.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за ссылку. Все что наследуется от Visual надо отобразить, иначе не печатается, эксперимент подтверждает. А как в ручную их рендерить пока не разобрался, с WPF знаком весьма поверхностно. Зато стимул копнуть глубже появился =) Вообще мне пока представляется что в WPF большую часть рутинных вещей делать сложнее чем в WinForms, а графические рюшечки - наоборот. Моя не понимать почему так. =)

Comment: Ну, вроде бы Grid наследуется от Panel -> FrameworkElement -> UIElement -> Visual (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). // Хм, мой опыт говорит, что рутинные вещи в WPF вообще не нужны, он их перебирает на себя (например, обмен данными между моделью и представлением и layout management). Но конечно надо выучить MVVM, это целый мир.

Comment: @VladD MVVM удобная штука, но иногда она избыточна что ли. Ощущение что кувалдой забиваешь сапожные гвоздики. Хотя может это вопрос привычки.

Comment: Ну, в маленьких проектах оно может и не особенно нужно. Но чем больше проект, тем больше оказывается нужно. (Это как с классами, в маленьких проектах они по сути не нужны.)

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но никак не могу разобраться как масштабировать изображение соразмерно области печати...

Comment: @Alexey добавил проверенный пример масштабирования. Спасибо можно сказать зеленой галочкой на ответе =)