# Как из приложения отправить что-либо на принтер?

Tags: c#, winforms, печать, принтер

Как из консольного приложения или приложения WinForms отправить что-либо на принтер?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Минимально необходимо для печати:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;

void Print()
{
  PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
  printDoc.PrintPage += PrintPageHandler;
  printDoc.Print();
}

void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  //Замените на e.Graphics.DrawImage или любую другую логику
  e.Graphics.DrawString("Привет", new Font("Arial", 14), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
}
```

при этом печать будет на дефолтном принтере. `PrintDialog` позволяет выбрать принтер и настроить некоторые параметры `PrintDocument` через диалоговое окно, но за печать отвечает именно `PrintDocument`.

Расширим пример для использования `PrintDialog`:

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrintPage += PrintPageHandler;
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.Document = printDoc;
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) printDialog.Document.Print();
```

Убираем всплывающие окошки, если в них нет необходимости:

```
printDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
```

По аналогии с добавлением `PrintDialog`, можно добавить `PageSetupDialog` и  `PrintPreviewDialog` последовательно передавая им объект `PrintDocument`.