# Послать биты на принтер

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
Есть тэрмопринтер работающий через usb. Сейчас биты на принтере отправляются с помощью конектора LibUsb, проблема именно в данной библиотеке т.к она требует установки в ОС.

Нужно сделать что бы программа работала без установки дополнительного софта. Может как то на прямую или может через драйвер самого принтера. Суть что бы отправлять байты из C# программы на принтер.

Comment: что за биты/байты вы собираетесь отправить на принтер? Для печати? тогда вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489415/198316)

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700954/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82-write-read]