# Таймаут Write Read

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

```
char inBuf[] = { 0x1d, 0x72 }; //0x1d, 0x72, 0x01
int inBufSize = sizeof(inBuf);
DWORD ReturnedLength = 0, eror;
byte sim[256];


hUsb = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)DeviceName, // Создание файла
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS |FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_EXECUTE ,
    NULL);




// очистка мусора порта
PurgeComm(hUsb, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
PurgeComm(hUsb, PURGE_TXCLEAR);

DCB dcb;
dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
dcb.fNull = FALSE;
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
dcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE;
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
SetCommState(hUsb, &dcb);


COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
// значений этих тайм – аутов вполне хватает для уверенного приема 
// даже на скорости 110 бод 
CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
// используется в данном случае как время ожидания посылки 
CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
bool yes=SetCommTimeouts(hUsb, &CommTimeOuts);
if (!yes)
    eror = GetLastError(); 

if (hUsb == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    statusLB->Text="Нет соединения";
    return;
}

    Success = WriteFile(hUsb, inBuf, inBufSize, &ReturnedLength, NULL);

    ReturnedLength = 0;

    Success = ReadFile(hUsb, &sim, sizeof(sim), &ReturnedLength, NULL );
```

getlasteror дает ошибку 1008 ругается на hUsb 
помогите

Все это при попытке отправить устройству биты(команды) есть команды которые не возращают бай. Естественно если команда ничего не возращает то на ReadFile будет тупняк пока не отсоеденишь устройство ли бо же не остановим отладку

Comment: Напишите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: ERROR_NO_TOKEN
1008 (0x3F0)
An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OVERLAPPED OverlapWRT;
OverlapWRT.OffsetHigh = 0;
OverlapWRT.Offset = 0;
OverlapWRT.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

OVERLAPPED OverlapRD;
OverlapRD.OffsetHigh = 0;
OverlapRD.Offset = 0;
OverlapRD.hEvent = NULL;

bool y = hUsb = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)wch,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);
Success = WriteFile(hUsb, inBuf, inBufSize, &ReturnedLength, &OverlapWRT);
Success = ReadFile(hUsb, &sim, sizeof(sim), &ReturnedLength, &OverlapRD);
```

Разобрался проблема была в асинхронной передаче.Заполнил структуру OVERLAPPED

Answer (score 0):

Для установки таймаутов на операции чтения/записи MS предлагает использование асинхронного механизма. Функции ReadFile/WriteFile вызываются с доп. параметром в виде overlapped-структуры и возвращают управление немедленно, а опрос состояния производится с помощью функции `GetOverlappedResult`, возвращающей ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE до тех пор, пока операция чтения/записи не будет завершена.

Пример кода (цикл чтения данных с внешнего устройства):

.h

```
OVERLAPPED m_ovWrite;   // Struct for writing process
OVERLAPPED m_ovRead;    // Struct for reading process
```

.cpp

```
ZeroMemory(&m_ovRead, sizeof(m_ovRead));
ZeroMemory(&m_ovWrite, sizeof(m_ovWrite));

m_ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
m_ovWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

...

do
{
    // Здесь может быть ваша проверка на таймаут

    if (ClearCommError(m_portHandle, &errorCode, &portState) == 0)
    {
        // Ошибка очистки 
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD currentReaded = 0;

    if (portState.cbInQue)
    {
        if (ReadFile(m_portHandle, buffer, min (portState.cbInQue, 4096), &currentReaded, &m_ovRead) == 0)
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                // Ошибка чтения
                return 0;
            }

            if (GetOverlappedResult(m_portHandle, &m_ovRead, &transfered, true) == 0)
            {
                // Ошибка ожидания
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // чтение блока данных успешно, сохраняем результат в буфер
    memcpy(readBuf + readed, buffer, currentReaded);
    readed += currentReaded;
}
while (readed != expectedLength);
```

Кроме этого есть функция `GetOverlappedResultEx` позволяющая задать таймаут ожидания одним из параметров (конкретно в моем случае она используется для ожидания ивентов на ком-порту).

Обмен данными с ком-портом можете организовать как синхронный (когда в ответ на каждую команду приходи подтверждение от устройства) либо асинхронный (когда существуют две очереди команд отправка/прием

По ошибке 1008, вы некорректно вызываете CreateFile(...), чему равен hUsb после вызова?

```
hUsb = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)DeviceName, // Создание файла
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    **OPEN_ALWAYS** |**FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED**,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | **FILE_EXECUTE** ,
    NULL);
```

OPEN_ALWAYS - позволяет открыть файл в случае физического отсутствия устройства, лучше использовать OPEN_EXISTING;

FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED - добавлен не туда

FILE_EXECUTE - это что за флаг, описания не нашел

Попробуйте так:

```
hUsb = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)DeviceName, // Создание файла
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);
```

описание структуры:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx

описание методов ReadFile/WriteFile (секция Remarks):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx

асинхронное ио:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: bool tr =hUsb = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)DeviceName, 
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
  NULL);
 if (!tr)
  eror = GetLastError();                                                                                  в таком случает Error = 0 но WriteFile не работает я смотрб снифером он  не отправляет никаких байт

Comment: Как по моему примеру сделать что бы не висело на рид файле ?

Comment: @PabloMurena, а почему оно там висит? устройство не посылает ответ?

Comment: Разобрался проблема была в асинхронной передаче.