# При печати, выводится пустая страница

Tags: c#, winforms

В директории с проектом хранится изображение в формате PNG. При печати, печатается пустая страница. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
private void bunifuThinButton22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.DocumentName = "Biernik.PNG";
            PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
            print.Document = doc;
            if (print.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                doc.Print();
            }
        }
```

Comment: вы забыли написать обработчик самой печати, поэтому и не печатает ни чего. Тут есть [рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489415/198316). Вам нужно заменить отрисовку текста на отрисовку картинки, естественно ее сначала надо прочитать из исходного файла.

Comment: `DocumentName` - это не имя файла, а отображаемое имя для принтера, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.documentname(v=vs.110).aspx