# C # для термопринтера xprinter

Tags: c#

Я новичок в печати чеков POS. После завершения транзакции мое приложение должно распечатать квитанцию ​​для клиента, использующего XPrinter

Comment: И в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Здравствуете как печать чеков на pos printer с c#

Comment: мой pos printer "xprinter xp"

Comment: Полистайте форум. Например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489414/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Если хочешь в чеке красивый шаблон, используй MS Office библиотеку, подгружай WORD документ и через Range Replace меняй на свои данные, потом прямо в печать через определенный принтер.. Будет всё красиво и круто!

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ