# Как из отдельных двух устройств принтера и сканера сделать копировальную машину

Tags: железо, документация, принтер, пк, сканирование

Есть желание создать программу, которая превратит отдельные сканер и принтер в копировальную систему. Хотел узнать как программно происходят процессы сканирования документа и его печати, но гугл не отвечает на эти вопросы. Какие ЯП мне потребуются, где узнать про низкоуровневые протоколы работы этих устройств? Заранее спасибо.

В конечном итоге хочу создать программу, которая по нажатию кнопки будет запускать сканирование листка бумаги в сканере, а потом автоматически отправлять уже электронный документ на печать в принтер. Оба устройства подключены к одному компьютеру через USB.

Comment: Скорее всего тут надо идти на сайт производителя и искать документацию конкретно под ваш принтер и сканер. Поидее, у производителя должно быть sdk как минимум для одного языка или же какие-нибудь bat файлы, которые запустят скан/печать

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что в документации на устройство есть объяснение как работает их ПО? Существуют ли отдельно какие-нибудь низкоуровневые ЯП, позволяющие взаимодействовать с подобными устройствами?

Comment: Поидее, +- такое должно быть. ЯП врятли есть такой, да и если подумать, любой яп позволяет взаимодействовать с портами, а значит и сингал на принтер сможет отправить. Напишите в поддержку компании ваших устройств, и спросите, по этому поводу. Это всяко лучше, чем гадать

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, ты хочешь написать прогу `iCopy`?

Comment: Я о такой программе и не знал, спасибо. Да, было бы интересно самостоятельно сделать такую программу, что понять как программно отправляются запросы на устройство и обратно. Гугл отвечает лишь как физически работают эти устройства.

Comment: @zetcan333 честно говоря не знаю как вы гуглили, по запросу первыми же ссылками выдаётся решение: https://habr.com/ru/post/322322/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489414/Как-из-приложения-отправить-что-либо-на-принтер