# Как рисовать на изображении или поверх? C#

Tags: c#, изображения, graphics, imageview

Первое на что я обратил внимание это то что у меня нету `PaintBox` в панели инструментов на `Visual Studio`, поэтому я использовал просто инструмент `Image`. Но теперь возникает вопрос, а как собственно на самой картинке что-то нарисовать, или поверх нее?
Я пробовал нарисовать картинку с помощью `System.Drawing.Image(Graphics.drawImage())` для того что бы с помощью `Graphics` там же рисовать на картинке, но у меня ничего не получилось, поэтому я использую `System.Windows.Controls.Image` для загрузки картинки, но не знаю как рисовать поверх или на ней.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Эм... действительно вопрос `System.Windows.Controls.Image` и `System.Drawing.Graphics` в одном месте... странно

Comment: @rdorn почему??

Comment: В WPF вроде свой ренедеринг, через `DrawingVisual` + `DrawingContext`, если не ошибаюсь. Понятно что совместить можно, но зачем?

Comment: Так все таки, приложение WPF или WinForms? от этого зависит решение

Comment: @rdorn WPF, в смысле совместить? Ну мне надо использовать либо `Windows.Controls` либо `Drawing.Image`. Мне в данном случае не имеет значение это, но я же говорю что с помощью `Drawing.Image` я не могу отобразить изображение на форме.

Comment: WPF позволяет рисовать используя возможности видеокарты и DirectX, хотя и со своей спецификой, тогда как WinForms использует GDI+, используя для отрисовки CPU. Ок, набросаю пример.

Comment: @rdorn буду очень благодарен)

Comment: копипастить примеры с мсдн не стал, но проверил, работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот на вскидку несколько вариантов:

[DrawingVisual - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual(v=vs.100).aspx). Напоминает `System.Drawing.Graphics` из GDI+ и также  содержит множество методов `DrawSomething()`. Этот класс используется также для [печати на принтере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489022/198316).

Если нужна относительно простая графика то вполне подойдет
[Canvas - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.100).aspx) и стандартные примитивы [Обзор фигур и базовых средств рисования в приложении WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx). "Относительно простая" - потому что при большом желании, к ним тоже можно прикрутить преобразования, анимацию и т.д. К тому же, с этими классами можно работать сразу в XAML.

В документации к классам есть рабочие примеры.

Думаю позже появится кто-нибудь из местных гуру по WPF и даст более качественный ответ.