# Как перевести Bitmap в таблицу или вектор?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, datagrid

Разрабатываю маленькую программку для создания макетов вышивки из изображений. Все алгоритмы уже проработаны. Все работает с учетом палитры ниток и т.п. Вот грубый результат без настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Теперь встал вопрос нанесения знаков в клетки для различия ниток (как это обычно делают в таких макетах). Изначально наносил их тем же Graphics, что и создавал шаблон. Но возникло две проблемы:

1. Чтобы уместить символ в клетке необходимо увеличить изображение в разы - страдает время, производительность и память.
2. С минимальным размером изображения, необходимым для читаемости символов макет выглядит мыльно. - печать выйдет в плохом качестве.

Посмотрев pdf макеты, выяснил, что там используется таблицы с раскрашенными ячейками и проставленными знаками в них. И тут в голову приходит только DataGrid (очень очень большой такой DataGrid).

Что хотелось бы узнать:

1. Правильным ли решением является использование DataGrid для этой цели? Также вопрос по производительности. А также как это все напечатать как вектор.
2. Может быть есть какие-нибудь компоненты для этой цели?

**UPD3:** Спасибо @VladD за наводку в сторону Canvas. Решился таки. Сделал по  [этому примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324359/add-n-rectangles-to-canvas-with-mvvm-in-wpf).

Теперь не знаю как выводить блоки асинхронно. Сам код расчета блоков сделать асинхронным не проблема, но вот дальше не знаю. Вешает UI.

Создал новый вопрос, так как проблема другая: [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562339/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-itemscontrol-%D1%81-canvas-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: Генерировать html, затем html преобразовывать в pdf.

Comment: html не вариант. Как я его буду выводить в UI, через WebBrowser? уж лучше через flowdocument. Но и этот вариант мне не нравится.

Comment: А почему не просто квадратики на Canvas?

Comment: @VladD а для таких квадратиков можно определить что именно в него кликнули и писать в нем обычные буковки?

Comment: @rdorn: `квадратик.MouseDown += OnКвадратикMouseDown`? А чтобы писать, положить внутрь `TextBlock`, это ж WPF.

Comment: @rdorn, а этого не потребуется.

Comment: @VladD, как это счастье скролить, оно ж все вылезает за границы контрола/окна и, самое главное, как на печать выводить (притом весь холст еще делить минимум на 4 части)?

Comment: @Salnik: Ну положите в `ScrollViewer`. Или сделайте квадратики поменьше. Или и то, и другое.

Comment: @Salnik: А про печать, [вот тут](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/02/201111.html) есть пример, разбирайтесь.

Answer (score 2):

Схему для вышивки можно представить в виде той же картинки с очень низким разрешением. Учитывая что палитра ниток сильно меньше палитры доступных для отображения цветов, можно воспользоваться простым приемом:

1. Подготовить (скачать или сделать) векторный шрифт с необходимыми значками.
2. Создать словарь соответствия символов и цветов.
3. Представить картинку как двумерный массив символов

И того вся картинка будет в среднем занимать несколько килобайт памяти. `Bitmap` для этого совсем не нужен. С моделью закончили. Думаю вы и сами до всего этого уже додумались.

Теперь дело за малым, показать это все в нужном виде. Сетку можно нарисовать и сохранить с помощью `GraphicsPath`. Его легко масштабировать и рисовать одной строкой. Но этот путь не даст вам интерактивности, т.е. придется городить неведому зверушку для определения в какую клеточку вы кликнули. Поэтому лучше воспользоваться советом **VladD**, и рисовать готовые квадратики нужного размера, исходя из масштаба, цвета, который выбираем из словаря, вписывать символы или цвет и символы сразу. При этом можно задать некий минимальный размер квадратика, при котором выводить только цвет без символа.

Такой подход позволит и память сэкономить, и не потерять качество картинки при сильном увеличении.

---

Добавим автоскрол для Canvas:

```
<ScrollViewer 
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas Height="2000px" Width="2000px">
    //тут рисуем квадратики
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

---

**[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489022/198316)** можно посмотреть про печать из WPF в принципе, а **[тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b26c7898-169a-4726-b582-e79dc63f8450/printing-canvas-using-printdialog-in-wpf?forum=wpf)** подсмотреть код печати контрола (Canvas - тоже контрол).

Comment: 1, 2 и 3 не проблема и решено или есть решение. Вариант от **VladD** не совсем подходит, тк:
 - все что в `Canvas` вылезает за границы контролов/окна.
 - как потом эту конструкцию вывести допустим на печать?
Просто представьте таблицу экселя с квадратными раскрашенными ячейками, внутри которых по одному символу - вот такое ищу.

Comment: нужно отображать всю картину целиком (с прокрутками). Сам PDF формат не нужен, нужна печать в векторе. Сейчас обновлю пост, нашел программу аналог.

Comment: обновил вопрос, прикрепил пример того, что ищу. должно именно скроллиться хотя бы. частичный рендер не подходит. Да по времени без разницы. Это чисто хобби для саморазвития))) Думал что уж на WPF есть простой способ или готовый контрол для таких извратов

Comment: все же не нравится мне идея с канвас и квадратиками. нужно подобие заполняемой сетки как `DataGrid`, так как нужно еще утолщенные линии каждые 10 клеток делать + разметка с цифрами, а это дополнительные элементы лепить и попадать координатами. Может как-то можно вывести изображение в вектор из `System.Drawing.Graphics` прям в контрол? Я в нем и делал все манипуляции (сетка и символы), но пока только знаю как в `Bitmap` вывести.

Comment: Перенес полезное в ответ, ненужные коментарии удалил. По поводу контрола сейчас гляну.

Comment: @Salnik: Вы почему-то всё время ожидаете, что в WPF найдётся контрол именно такого вида, как вам надо, и вы просто скормите ему пару байт данных, и он всё хорошо и правильно нарисует. Нет, такого не бывает. Всю «красоту» наподобие разделительных линий или заголовков строк/столбцов должны нарисовать на окне лично вы как автор программы.

Comment: @VladD, мои ожидания связаны с тем, что уже много чего написано и придумано, грубо говоря не хотелось городить велосипед.=D Как, например, с алгоритмом пикселизации в моей программе, просто был взят удобный framework (конечно сначала написал свой - кривой). Опять же с `DataGrid` я бы это провернул, но он не подходит для такого объема.

Comment: @Salnik: `DataGrid` вовсе не предназначен для того, что вы хотите. Он предназначен для отображения данных из таблицы. То, что некоторые визуальные элементы в нём похожи на то, что вам нужно — случайность. В частности, вам вряд ли удастся так просто заставить `DataGrid` сделать свои ячейки квадратными. А уж изменение толщины линий требует вовсе высшего пилотажа. Так что проще нарисовать самостоятельно, поверьте.

Comment: @VladD я совсем забыл сказать откуда также такое желание готового контрола, кроме не желания велосипеда. Все стоит на MVVM. Так как подключается база с нитками. Там же (в командах ViewModel) создается макет, и он в том или ином виде должен передаваться во View. Хотя тут я мог и погорячиться, ограничившись лишь на базе.

Comment: @Salnik задайте шаблон для контента (вериткальная и горизонтальная линейки с цифрами и клеточки между ними) и забиндите канвас на массив, чем не MVVM?

Comment: @Salnik: Окей, MVVM — это аргумент. Но всё равно, `DataGrid` принимает на вход последовательность последовательностей, а не квадратные таблицы. `Canvas` с кастомной отрисовкой вполне может быть View-имплементацией для вашей VM. (Да, это имплементация не из стандартных контролов, ну так и ваша задача не из стандартных!) Просто подпишитесь на `DataContextChanged` и передобавляйте ваши квадраты на `Canvas`.

Comment: @VladD, обновил шапку вопроса. Возникла проблема с асинхронным выводом в `Canvas`.

Comment: @Salnik: Если есть новая проблема, имеет смысл задать новый вопрос. А то что делать с ответами на предыдущую редакцию вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `OpenGL` (в данном случаи [SharpGL](https://sharpgl.codeplex.com/)).
Для такой задачи может и слишком тяжелый инструмент, но раз у вас возникают такие сложности, думаю поможет.
Предоставляет большие возможности при высокой скорости. Возможно для ваших проблем найдется красивое решение.

Тоже раньше были похожие проблемы, не поленился, потратил время на `OpenGL` и был приятно удивлен. Можно сколь угодно крутить, вертеть, увеличивать/уменьшать, рисовать быстрые динамичные сцены - никаких тормозов при высоком качестве.

**UPD**
Примеры для `SharpGL`: на сайте скачиваем [Samples](https://sharpgl.codeplex.com/releases) (исходники тут: [SharpGL/Samples/](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl/tree/master/source/SharpGL/Samples)).

Для информации (см. [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)):

> `OpenGL` - спецификация, определяющая платформонезависимый (независимый от языка программирования) программный интерфейс для написания приложений, использующих двумерную и трёхмерную компьютерную графику.

`SharpGL` только один из примеров библиотек для `.Net`, предоставляющих доступ к `OpenGL`. Есть еще например `OpenTK`, `Tao Framework`.

Comment: ТС хочет уйти от ручной отрисовки в область MVVM и применения стандартных контролов, а вы советуете ему прямо противоположное: опуститься на уровень графических примитивов.

Comment: @VladD Тем не менее, это могло бы решить задачу. В вопросе же как раз про производительность, качество, Graphics, Canvas написано? Думаю, ответ уместен для поставленного вопроса.

Comment: @Ildar SharpGL не имеет документации. Даже простых примеров нет. Удалось сетку нарисовать, но через костыль. Буду признателен, если Вы поможете. Мне то всего надо узнать как рисовать: сетку (точнее массив линий), массив прямоугольников и массив символов. Линии и прямоугольники получились (спустя несколько часов), а вот с массивами проблема. А без них падает производительность.

Comment: @Salnik Обновил ответ. Примеры есть на сайте, исходники примеров на гит-хабе.

Comment: @Ildar видел я эти примеры. Самая плохая докумениация, что я видел. У меня времени уйдет пол года на изучение. Хотелось бы найти готовые реализации таких вещей. Но ничего не могу найти. Не имею столько времени и желания.

Comment: @Salnik Пардон, а что вы хотите? Что бы в примерах была именно ваша программа? Сколько еще документаций (других проектов) вы прошли, что делаете такие выводы? Такими методами обучения и пол года не хватит.

Comment: @Salnik Примеры нормальные, сопровождены пояснительными комментариями. Для понимания этого кода, нужно быть знакомым с `OpenGL` (например [тут](http://www.opengl.org.ru/lesson/index.html)). `SharpGL` - всего лишь библиотека, предоставляющая доступ к `OpenGL`.

Comment: @Ildar ну, например, хотелось бы видеть доки как AForge, MVVM Light и тп. Одно только радует - синтаксис у OpenGL похож на разных языках. Извиняюсь конечно, но почему все твердят одно и то же? Я сначала ищу готовое, разбираюсь и делаю. Если готового нет - читаю, изучаю что есть. Иначе зачем я бы спрашивал на форуме? Поиски не дают даже приближенных результатов. И к слову сетка то должна была бы быть кем-то реализована, тем более в для OpenGL

Comment: @Ildar проблема даже не в том, что я не могу сделать, а в том что сильно падает fps, даже при небольшой сетке. Удалось оптимизировать до 50fps. Но это только сетка, а еще будут полигоны/прямоугольники (много) и текст. И боюсь, запаса просто fps не хватит.

Comment: @Salnik Увы, больше ничем помочь не смогу. Если `OpenGL`  тормозит при таких fps, может вы не так рисуете? Думаю, если у вас возникли затруднения по этому поводу, имеет смысл задать новый вопрос (тут или в специализированных форумах).