# Как передать коллекцию прямоугольников в ItemsControl с Canvas асинхронно?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, асинхронность, tpl

При решении [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561861/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-bimap-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), возник новый.

Что делаю: из ViewModel передаю коллекцию прямоугольников, вот так:

```
public async void Start()
{
    RectItems.Clear();

    CrossStitch cs = new CrossStitch()
    {
        BlockSize = _blockSize,
        Source = _sourceImage
    };

    var data = await cs.Create();

    foreach (var r in data)
        RectItems.Add(r);

}
```

Получаю во View вот так:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="2000" Height="2000"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding C}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Все замечательно работало, до того как метод `Start()` стал `async`. Теперь я получаю вместо результата, это:

> Необходимо создать DependencySource в том же потоке, в котором создан DependencyObject.

Нашел только одну похожую проблему, но в ней передавалось изображение в `Canvas`, и проблема решалась вызовом `Freeze` у изображения. А как быть в моем случае?

Метод `Create` и прилежащие:

```
public Task<List<RectItem>> Create()
{
    return PixelateAsync(_source);
}

private Task<List<RectItem>> PixelateTask(Bitmap source)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Pixelate(source));
}

private Task<List<RectItem>> PixelateAsync(Bitmap source)
{
    return PixelateTask(source);
}
```

`Pixelate(source)` синхронный.

Класс `RectItem`:

```
public class RectItem
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush C { get; set; }
}
```

Метод Pixelate весь:

```
private List<RectItem> Pixelate(Bitmap source)
    {
        var result = new Bitmap(source);

        List<RectItem> rectangs = new List<RectItem>();

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x += _blockSize)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y += _blockSize)
                {
                    var sums = new Sums();

                    for (int xx = 0; xx < _blockSize; ++xx)
                    {
                        for (int yy = 0; yy < _blockSize; ++yy)
                        {
                            if (x + xx >= source.Width || y + yy >= source.Height)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            var color = source.GetPixel(x + xx, y + yy);
                            sums.A += color.A;
                            sums.R += color.R;
                            sums.G += color.G;
                            sums.B += color.B;
                            sums.T++;
                        }
                    }

                    var average = Color.FromArgb(
                        sums.A / sums.T,
                        sums.R / sums.T,
                        sums.G / sums.T,
                        sums.B / sums.T);

                    average = GetNearestColor(average);
                    System.Windows.Media.Color mcolor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(average.A, average.R, average.G, average.B);
                    System.Windows.Media.Brush brush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(mcolor);
                    rectangs.Add(new RectItem()
                    {
                        X = x + BlockSize,
                        Y = y + BlockSize,
                        Height = BlockSize,
                        Width = BlockSize,
                        C = brush
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return rectangs;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите ваш метод `Create`, проблема в нём.

Comment: @VladD добавил в вопрос код.

Comment: Не, уже вроде бы неправильно. `RectItem` — VM-объект? Тогда вы не должны создавать его в фоновом потоке (`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Pixelate(source));`). Давайте код `Pixelate`, будем приводить к тому, что надо.

Comment: @VladD добавил код.

Comment: Получилось проще, чем я ожидал, сработал трюк с `Freeze()`. (Он не работал бы, если бы ваша VM имела thread affinity, то есть была бы привязана к конкретному потоку.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. Проблема в том, что VM-классы создаются в фоновом потоке, это в обычной ситуации неправильно.

Но в вашем случае `RectItem` — не `DependencyObject`, а значит, он не привязан к определённому потоку. Поэтому можно пойти более простым путём: создавать этот объект где угодно. Единственная проблема, которую нужно вынести в UI — создание `Brush`. Но `Brush` является `Freezable`- значит, его можно также создавать где угодно, просто нужно  после создания вызвать `brush.Freeze();`.

Ещё один framework-класс — `Color` — тоже не является проблемой, т. к. он не является ни `DependencyObject`'ом, ни `Freezable`.

Итого: просто добавьте после

```
System.Windows.Media.Brush brush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(mcolor);
```

строку

```
brush.Freeze();
```

Comment: заработало, но основную задачу это не решило. UI все равно зависает после создания коллекции прямоугольников. Отвисает только при появлении изображения в `Canvas`. Как быть?

Comment: @Salnik: Ну, это уже за рамками данного вопроса. Раз ваша машина не тянет 4 миллиона UI-элементов, придётся рисовать вручную. Например, уберите Canvas, положите вместо него ваш собственный контрол, унаследованный от чего-то простого (например, от `Panel`), и перекройте в нём [`OnRender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender(v=vs.110).aspx) (там по ссылке и пример есть). Внутри можно будет посмотеть в ваш `DataContext` и отрисовать то, что нужно, вручную. Быстрее, чем это, в WPF не бывает.

Comment: ну почему же за рамками? Вопрос подразумевает асинхронную загрузку, т.е. чтобы UI не вешало. К слову, элементов там порядка 1000, так как я проверял на самом минимуме. Т.е. это все таки проблема отрисовки, а не привязки?

Comment: @Salnik: Ну, вопрос был об асинхронном построении VM, а не о полной отладке вашего приложения (за второе я бы не взялся). Что реально является причиной зависания UI, должны выяснить вы сами, с профайлером в руках. (В VS 2015, кажется, встроен какой-то. Если он не катит, возьмите [trial'ьный Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), например.) Вопрос отладки приложений достаточно сложен, так что вряд ли так просто можно угадать заранее, что будет тормозить.

Comment: @Salnik: В любом случае, 4 миллиона UI-элементов — это реально много для WPF.

Comment: ну я решил проблему оставив только один `Canvas` и передаю ему `VirtualHost`, в котором рисую. Разгрузка почти сразу происходит, но теперь `Canvas` тормозит жутко при прокрутке (в варианте с долгой загрузкой не тормозило). Я уже скоро волосы начну рвать =D

Comment: @Salnik: (1) А зачем вам промежуточный Canvas? (2) Ну так отпрофилируйте же! Как можно без профайлера угадать, что именно тормозит? Ну или посмотрите, сколько раз вызывается `OnRender`, да, _может быть_, он вызывается при скролле слишком часто. Возможно, имеет смысл закешировать то, что в OnRender вычисляется. [Но это я тут пытаюсь играть роль профайлера.]

Comment: (2)на этом (профайлер) мои знания заканчиваютсям =D 
(1) Лень было возится с привязками к самому `Host`. 
Подцепил `CashMode` в `Canvas` стало скролить быстрее, если тянуть за бары (мышкой также глючит).
P.S.: наверное единственное правильное решение - найти подходящую для цели среду/платформу. wpf совсем мимо =D

Comment: @Salnik: WPF — прекрасная платформа, 4КК объектов вам не отрисует быстро никто. Ну и всё же вы бы сделали отрисовку через `OnRender` перед тем, как ругать WPF.

Comment: платформа мб и да, но для этой цели нужен Direct или OpenGL, но ни как не контролы wpf. Но в силу их сложности желания их трогать нет.
`OnRender` в кастомном `Canvas`. Как мне передать колекцию? Что-то везде приводят способ с `ItemsControl`, от которого я ушел. Да и как мне вызывать то `OnRender` когда коллекция обновляется? Я тоже самое сделал, только в методе, который вызывается при обновлении коллекции.

Comment: @Salnik: Мне сложно видеть ваши аргументы по поводу необходимости DirectX. В любом случае, в том же DirectX вам точно так же пришлось бы отрисовывать ваши контролы вручную (т. к. это **очень** низкоуровневый фреймворк), ну и разумеется, что с MVVM пришлось бы попрощаться. Окей, теперь по делу. Коллекцию передавайте как обычно, через DataContext. OnRender вам самостоятельно вызывать не надо, когда возникнет необходимость в перерисовке, вызывайте `InvalidateVisual`, `OnRender` будет вызвано фреймворком.

Comment: а можно пример с передачей коллекция? Я не понимаю как это сделать? У меня сейчас рабочих два варианта: 
(1) `ItemsControl` получает коллекцию, а дальше `Canvas` подхватывает прямоугольники.
(2) `VisualHost` как свойство `ViewModel`, которое цепляю к `ContentPresenter` у `Canvas`.
А создать и связать свойство (как коллекцию) в  кастомном `Canvas` не получается. +использую MVVM Light

Comment: @Salnik: (1) Выкиньте канвас, он не нужен. (2) Вместо него положите ваш класс, производный от Panel. У него не должно быть никаких child-элементов, он всё рисует сам. (3) Для этого он переопределят `OnRender` и подписывается на DataContextChanged (4) В DataContext передаёте `List<RectItem>`.

Comment: (1) Выкинул. (2)Panel не скролится совсем. (3)при каждом изменении размера окна рендерит заного, не лучше ли вызывать отдельный мето? А вот с DataContextChanged не понял. Мой контрол подписывается на событие ViewModel? (4) Передал, выводит только когда меняю размер окно (вызывается Onrender).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44877/discussion-between-salnik-and-vladd).