# Виснет Canvas при прокрутке

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

И снова я в продолжении [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561861/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-bimap-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), который оброс новыми. Надеюсь в последний раз.

В решении задачи нашлось два способа вывода большого числа элементов в `Canvas`.

**Первый:**

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Pattern.RectSize, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Height="{Binding Pattern.RectSize, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Fill="{Binding Fill}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Второй**(большое спасибо @VladD):

```
public class SchemeCanvas: Panel
{
    ...
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
        ...
    }
}
```

+

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <controls:SchemeCanvas/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

НО. В первом способе, загрузка данных происходит очень долго, вешая при этом UI, но прокрутка работает отлично. Во втором способе изображение появляется почти мгновенно, но прокрутка тормозит.

Как я понимаю, первый способ предполагает `AddChild` в `Canvas`, а второй отрисовку коллекции целиком.

Как решить эту(-и) проблему(-ы)? Как объединить скорость загрузки и плавность прокрутки?

`ZoomableCanvas` и `VirtualizedCanvas` из блога msdn мне не помогли. Подключал все по примерам. `ZoomableCanvas` дает тот же результат, `VirtualizedCanvas` тормозит совсем и приходится создавать еще кучу кода для приведения своего типа в нужный.

P.S.: от OpenGL отказался в сторону простоты и печати.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос. Решил пойти следующим путем:
Завернул в `Canvas`(который сам находится в `ScrollViewer`) три элемента: `Image`и два `Canvas` (или что-нибудь `FrameworkElement`). В `Image` передаю `Bitmap`, растянутый `LayoutTransform` до нужного размера на:

```
double Scale = BlockSize/PixelSaze
```

где `BlockSize` - размер сетки и отображаемых пикселей,
`PixelSize` - размер фильтра пикселизации.

Размер `Canvas` делаю так:

```
Width = Scale * Bitmap.Width // + Padding, если нужны поля
Height = Scale * Bitmap.Height // + Padding, если нужны поля
```

Такие же размеры остальным слоям. И с помощью `BlockSize` задаю размер сетки.

В третий слой в `OnRender` вывожу буквы. Тут приходится подключать `CacheMode`. Работает гладко. Печатается хорошо, но с одной оговоркой.