# Принцип вывода документа на печать

Tags: c#, печать

Каков принцип вывода документа на печать? Всякий ли файл конвертируется в изображение перед отправкой на принтер. Т.е. если я создал таблицу в своей программе, то для вывода на печать я должен пробежаться по всем ячейкам и с помощью графического компонента нарисовать эту таблицу с ее содержимым на листе и передать изображение на вывод. Это единственный способ(Не берем в расчет сохранение в файл и печать из внешней программы например excel)? Пишу на c# .net, но вопрос относится, думаю, не только к нему.

Comment: Пожалуйста расширьте свой вопрос, он не позволяет дать однозначного ответа.

Comment: Кратко: нет, не каждый файл. В частности, смотрите [PostScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript).

Comment: Зависит от вашего графического фреймворка. WPF и WinForms делают это по-разному.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489415/198316 WinForms
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489022/198316 WPF
Это что касается печати из приложения на C# возможно есть еще что-то, но я про это, к сожалению, не знаю.